# Photon Fusion Game Disconnecting Error = DisconnectedByPluginLogic

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am working on a turn-based multiplayer game and it’s headless build is hosted on PlayFab and multiplayer is built using Fusion SDK. The problem I am facing for the past few days is that when two players are playing the game sometimes the server disconnects with the log showing “PhotonCloudTimeout” and “DisconnectedByPluginLogic”
As per the documentation I cannot find why these error arises and how we can resolve this issue?

I have tried changing Photon Network Settings i.e. Region but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.